# Read texts using sscanf

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I have a question regarding to usage of sscanf function.

```
#include  <iostream>
#include  <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[3];
    char b[4];
    const char* p = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbb";
    sscanf(p, "%2s %3s", a, b);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The desired output would be:
aa
bbb

Actual output is:
aa
aaa

Comment: Your format string means "read two characters, then skip over whitespace — if there is any — then read three characters", and that's what happened.

Comment: @molbdnilo  `"%2s %3s"` more closely means "skip over whitespace, if any, read 1 to 2 non-white-space characters, skip over whitespace, if any, read 1 to 3 non-white-space characters".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to skip all characters up to a space, use `%*[^ ]`:

```
sscanf(p, "%2s%*[^ ] %3s", a, b);
```

The asterisk after `%` tells `sscanf` to ignore the corresponding portion of the input.

This produces the desired output ([demo 1](http://ideone.com/Nta5Of)).

> why this case is not working?
>
> ```
> char a[5];
> char b[6];
> const char* p = "word word2 , word";
> sscanf(p, "%4s%*[^ ] %5s", a, b);
> ```

This does not work because `%s` and `%[...]` do not mix very well. Replace `%Ns` with `%N[^ ]`:

```
sscanf(p, "%4[^ ]%*[ ]%5[^ ]", a, b);
```

[demo 2](http://ideone.com/sIzlAI).