# Proper usage of sscanf function

Tags: c++, standard-library

The following code crashes or doesn't work properly when I change

`sscanf(data, "%s %s", w1, w2);`

to

`sscanf(data, "%4s %5s", w1, w2);`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    const char *data = " w2o@raaaaa , anun , anun56";
    char w1[5], w2[6], w3[4];
    sscanf(data, "%s %s", w1, w2); 
    cout<<w1<<endl;
    cout<<w2<<endl;
    return(0);
}
```

Is there any format which fully complies with "%s %s", but buffers don't get overflowed.

Desired output would be:

> w2o@
>
> anun

Actual output:

> Buffer overflow.

Comment: Since you are using C++, it is preferable to use `std::string` and `std::cin`.

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079403/read-texts-using-sscanf   Hmm  Why the new user name?

Comment: If you're doing C++, stick with std lib, as @myaut said. `std::stringstream` will be useful too.

Comment: You've not scanned past the comma, so you won't get `arun`.  AFAICR, if you limit the input with `%4s`, then the conversion picks up where that left off — rather than reading to the end of a long field, truncating the result and then moving on.

Comment: Use `"%4s%*[^ ,] ,%5s"` and check that the result of `sscanf()` is 2.

Comment: Very grateful it really works properly